# Torque problem solving question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

I understand torque is a vector and thus has both a magnitude and direction and that we normally set CCW rotation as positive and vice versa but for a lot of the problems I do, I see the sign in front of the torque being ignored/not included.

A simple example of this:
"A student pulls down with a force of 40N on a rope that winds around a pulley of radius of 5." The diagram included shows the pulley rotating clockwise due to the rope pulling it.

My textbook says that the answer is τ = rFsin(θ) = 2 N*m.

I understand how we get the value however isn't CW rotation considered negative? Or is it just common to not include the sign with these types of problems.

Sorry for the poor formatting, I only recently started using this platform.

Edit:

For another problem: A block of mass m is hung from a pulley of radius R and mass M and is allowed to fall. What is the acceleration of the block.
[image]

If I define the down direction as positive. Would I consider my CW rotation to be positive as well?

Comment: Hi. This is a HW&E question. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: No, these are not homework questions. Not sure what "HW&E" stands for and yes I've done them myself. I get the right answer but I don't really understand why they choose the sign on torque isn't there. Does it not matter for these types of problems?

Comment: HW&E stands for Home Work and Exercise. A question does not have *literally* to be homework to qualify as HW&E. Yours does, believe me.

Comment: For the second problem in the edit, I solved it by finding the tension force using τ=Iα=Ftr and writing it in terms of tangential acceleration. I then used fnet = ma for the block to solve for the acceleration of the block.  The issue I had with the problem was more conceptual, I didn't understand why the torque in the answers was positive when Ft was causing CW rotation which I still don't fully understand. Is it because I define my down direction as positive and thus CW rotation is also now considered positive based on how I defined it?

Comment: IWhy didn't you include the solution to the second problem in your question?

Comment: A radius of 5 what?

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since torque is a vector, it makes sense to talk about its magnitude.  Recall that the torque $\vec{\boldsymbol \tau}$ is defined as $$\vec{\boldsymbol \tau}=\bf\vec r\times \vec F$$ and its magnitude $\tau = \| \vec{\boldsymbol \tau} \|$ is therefore $$\tau = rF\sin\theta$$ which is the given answer.

In intro physics, torque will usually be either clockwise or counterclockwise about one axis, so we can get away with just working with the magnitude.

Comment: I see thanks for the clarification! For the second problem however I don't see why we can ignore the sign on torque as we use τnet = Iα, so shouldn't the sign matter?

Comment: In order to use some sign convention you need to define a coordinate system $x,y,z$. Things follow from there.

Comment: Sorry for the barrage of questions, thanks I appreciate it a lot. 
Is it because I define my down direction as positive which is why the CW rotation is now considered positive and thus torque done by the tension is positive?

Comment: @michael yes, exactly.  It's like in 1D projectile motion we can define the downwards motion as positive so the acceleration is positive.